# How to calculate expiring voucher balances

Tags: sql-server, window-functions

I have a simple table for vouchers that subscribers buy to enable usage minutes on a system

then a table for usages that were actually used

now, to figure out the balance should be pretty simple with a window function. problem is, that some of the vouchers have expiration dates. And for the life of me I can't figure out how to exclude usages after the expiration date. Here is a very simple fiddle:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Vouchers](
    [SubscriptionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [AddedOn] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Cost] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Expiry] [datetime2](7) NULL)   
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Usages](
    [Date] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [SubscriptionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Price] [money] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL)
GO
INSERT INTO Vouchers (SubscriptionID,AddedOn,Cost,Expiry) Values (1,'2000-01-01',100,NULL)
INSERT INTO Vouchers (SubscriptionID,AddedOn,Cost,Expiry) Values (1,'2000-02-01',100,'2000-02-25')
INSERT INTO Vouchers (SubscriptionID,AddedOn,Cost,Expiry) Values (1,'2000-03-01',100,NULL)
INSERT INTO Usages (SubscriptionID,Date,Price) Values (1,'2000-01-01',50)
INSERT INTO Usages (SubscriptionID,Date,Price) Values (1,'2000-02-01',70)
INSERT INTO Usages (SubscriptionID,Date,Price) Values (1,'2000-02-28',30)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/68f03

This is my current query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY subscriptionid ORDER BY date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Balance
from (
SELECT SubscriptionID, AddedOn as Date, Cost as Amount
 from vouchers
UNION
SELECT       SubscriptionID, Date, -Price  
FROM Usages)t
```

If you run this in the fiddle, You will see the last line has a balance of 0. Which is wrong. The second voucher expires midmonth. So the last 50 dollars cannot be calculated in the voucher. And the customer should be in a minus 50.

I would appreciate any help

Thanks!

Comment: You've got AddedOn and Expiry but Expiry is completely unused. Another UNION of SubscriptionID, Expiry and -Cost FROM vouchers might be a starting point

Comment: Hi. I appreciate your input. But adding that line will completely redact the entire amount of the voucher. which would be inaccurate. We only want to redact those minutes that were used after the date of expiry. Thanks.

Comment: where are minutes used coming from? and how do you make sure that they get used against the February voucher and not the January or February ones which do not expire?

Comment: Hi. The minutes are coming from the Usages table. There I know every day how many units were used on that day. Regarding how do i know against which voucher to check them. that's precisely my question: How can I check each day's minutes only against vouchers that were not yet expired.

Comment: At the moment your only usage is on 2000-01-01 so how could that have come off the voucher that wasn't applied until 2000-02-01? You'll need to join Usage to Voucher with some kind of date filtering to work out the month residual balance, then look at expiration after that

Comment: Hi. It seems like someone "fiddled" with my fiddle. Im editing my post with the full build.